# Interpolator vs Animations vs Transitions

Tags: android, animation, android-transitions

I'm researching a lot about android animations and material design and now I a little confused about the concept of each "animation type".

From Android developers site:

[Animations](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/index.html)

Animations can add subtle visual cues that notify users about what's going on in your app and improve their mental model of your app's interface. Animations are especially useful when the screen changes state, such as when content loads or new actions become available. Animations can also add a polished look to your app, which gives your app a higher quality feel.

[Interface Interpolator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Interpolator.html)

An interpolator defines the rate of change of an animation. This allows the basic animation effects (alpha, scale, translate, rotate) to be accelerated, decelerated, repeated, etc.

[Transitions Framework](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/overview.html)

Animating your app's user interface provides more than just visual appeal. Animations highlight changes and provide visual cues that help users learn how your app works.

So here goes the question, **Whats the practical difference between them? And Which one should I use?**

Comment: Did my answer help clear up any confusion you had?

Answer (score 2):

I try my best to explain this I'm definitely no expert.

Lets start with Interpolator. It is a timing utility, required for all animations in Android. They allow you to customize your animation using their timing curve. For example, the LinearInterpolator has a constant rate of change meaning that whatever you are animating will always have constant changes. So if you are animating an image 100 pixels horizontally, over 1 second at 60fps. The image will move about 6~ pixels every 16 milliseconds. But with a AccelerateInterpolator, the rate of change will increase periodically based on some easing factor you apply to the interpolators constructor. Using the previous example, it would not move consistently by 6~ pixels every 16 milliseconds, but instead the amount of pixels the image moves by will slightly increase until the animations completes. Here is a [link](https://material.io/guidelines/motion/duration-easing.html) to the material doc that contains some very useful videos that demonstrate how interpolators effect animations. I recommend reading through the entire page and maybe the next to get a better grasp.

Next, transitions are a specific type of animation. Transitions will animate between changes in state; such as Activities, UI elements or text. For example, if you are switching between Activities in you app, the framework provides a default animation that transitions the two Activities. This transition is usually a slide-in and out translation. Another transition animation example, is when you tap an image and the app transitions to another screen containing the same tapped image. Think clicking album art inside of Play Music. Here is a [link](https://material.io/guidelines/motion/material-motion.html#material-motion-what-makes-a-good-transition) of a good transition animation from the material design doc (View the first video).